# ionic http.get doesn't work in factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So i can get data from a URL if i do it from with in my controller. But if i take that and move it into a factory it doesn't work. So what am i doing wrong?

```
angular.module('starter.notifications', [])

.factory('Notifications', function($http) {
  var link = "http://localhost:8000/notifications";
  var notifications = [];
  return {
    getAll: function()
    {
      return $http.get(link).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          notifications = data;
          return notifications;          
      });

    },
```

This code works if i move it into a controller, but why doesn't it work in a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it.

In the top of your app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.services','ngCordova'])
```

Let ionic knows you have an services.js by declaring it.

services.js (an http post request example)

```
    angular.module('app.services', ['ngCordova'])

.factory('dataFactory', function($http, $cordovaGeolocation){

    var dataFactory = {};


    dataFactory.login = function(username, password){

        var config = {

            headers:  {

                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }
        var data = 'userID=' + username + '&password=' + password +'';
        var httpAddressDoLogin = "http://YOURURL";
    return $http.post(httpAddressDoLogin, data, config);

    };

    return dataFactory;


})
```

In your controller:

```
dataFactory.login(username, password).then(function(resp) {
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On services.js $http.get resulting promise not object array. To make it work write like this on your services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Actor', function($http) {
var actors = $http.get('http://ringkes/slim/snippets/actor').then(function(resp) {
if (resp) { 
return = resp['data'];// This will produce promise, not array so can't call directly
} else {
console.error('ERR', err);
}
});
return {
all: function() {
  return actors;
}
};
});
```

then call it on controller like this:

```
controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,Actor,$http) {
Actor.all().then(function(actors){ $scope.actors = Actor.all();
});
});
```